# change base url of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, microsoft-edge, digest-authentication

I have an angular app which runs on http://192.168.1.1/

but the problem is in edge browser digest authentication don't work for url

http://192.168.1.1/ it needs something for the / like /home

how to redirect user when he first loads http://192.168.1.1/ to http://192.168.1.1/home and digest authentication kicks in for that.

Comment: That's entirely in the configuration of your web server, nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

inside your app-routing.module you can specify that on load to the base the user is redirected to another url. i.e:

`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
}`

You can then add the `canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard]` to your router for the component you have redirected them too. This is how I have is in my application